# How to configure filesystems to send images from one Laravel application to another?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

My application consists of two different laravel applications.

One, (**APP-A**) is the front end for users.

Another (**APP-B**) is the backoffice, used only by content managers.

Both consume the same database.

The problem to be solved has to do with the storage of images and other files.

During development, **I want to store the images in APP-B storage**.

For this, I need to send the images from APP-A to APP-B and perform the other applicable CRUD operations.

How should I configure filesystems.php for this purpose? Do I have to do it in APP-A and APP-B filesystems? And file .env?

**EDITED 17/03**

**APP-B  (backoffice)**

Folders:
Storage/uploadFiles/images

*filesystems.php*

```
uploadFiles' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/uploadFiles'),
],

'links' => [
    public_path('uploadFiles') => storage_path('app/uploadFiles')
],
```

On APP-B controllers to read images from APP-B storage

```
$url = asset('images/');
```

**On APP-A (Front End for users)**

*.env file*

```
ASSET_URL= http://my_app.dv/uploadFiles/
```

Note: *php artisan config:clear* required

For read images stored in APP-B from APP-A controller , just:

```
$url = asset('images')
```

It works.

Problem to solve: store a image in APP-B storage from a APP-A controller

```
$file = $request->file('file');
$path = $file->store('images');
```

This will store in APP-A instead of App-B as desired.
How to solve this (for development purposes only)?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up AWS S3 for both applications and use the same key in both applications to access the same bucket. Result: Both applications uses the same "storage directory".

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I need to make this work in my development environment just between two different laravel apps or another local solution to share images between the two applications that may be in different domains

Comment: If app B is running a SFTP server you could set up app A to use SFTP to access the same dir as app B

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I edited my post with solutions for read operations. The problem is the other CRUD operations.